# How can I make an array instead of nested arrays in Javascript from myArray?

Tags: javascript

I need to split riskTypeNo from each object and then assign selectedValue to each value and then create an array with all the objects. With my code I am getting nested arrays

```
    const myArray = [
  {
    "fieldID": 1681977,
    "riskTypeNo": "A1;M1",
    "selectedValue": "4"
  },
  {
    "fieldID": 1681984,
    "riskTypeNo": "C6;M1",
    "selectedValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "fieldID": 1682084,
    "riskTypeNo": "A13;C6;M1;D5",
    "selectedValue": "3"
  }
];


console.log(
    myArray.map(item1 => {
    const riskTypeNo =  item1.riskTypeNo.split(";").map(item2 => ({ "riskTypeNo": item2,  "selectedValue": item1.selectedValue }));
    return riskTypeNo;   
  })
);
```

Desired Result is:

```
[ 
{ riskTypeNo: "A1", selectedValue: "4" }, { riskTypeNo: "M1", selectedValue: "4" }], [{ riskTypeNo: "C6", selectedValue: "1" }, { riskTypeNo: "M1", selectedValue: "1" }], [{ riskTypeNo: "A13", selectedValue: "3" }, { riskTypeNo: "C6", selectedValue: "3" }, { riskTypeNo: "M1", selectedValue: "3" }, { riskTypeNo: "D5", selectedValue: "3" } 
}]
```

Comment: You are already getting your desired result (which is an array of arrays). Or do you have a typo in "Desired Result is […]" ?

Comment: With my code I am getting nested arrays instead of 1 array with objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this method instead :

```
const newArray = [];
myArray.forEach((item1) => {
  item1.riskTypeNo.split(";").forEach((item2) => {
    newArray.push({ riskTypeNo: item2, selectedValue: item1.selectedValue });
  });
});
```

result will be in `newArray`.

Answer (score 2):

You can return the split array from inside the `map` method. But that will get you an array of arrays. To flatten those arrays just use the array method `flat`.

This should work:

```
const result = myArray.map(el => {
    const riskTypes = el.riskTypeNo.split(";").map(riskTypeNo => ({
        riskTypeNo,
        selectedValue: el.selectedValue,
    }))
    return riskTypes;                                           
}).flat();
```

Comment: I like this better than mine. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```js
const myArray = [
  {
    "fieldID": 1681977,
    "riskTypeNo": "A1;M1",
    "selectedValue": "4"
  },
  {
    "fieldID": 1681984,
    "riskTypeNo": "C6;M1",
    "selectedValue": "1"
  },
  {
    "fieldID": 1682084,
    "riskTypeNo": "A13;C6;M1;D5",
    "selectedValue": "3"
  }
];

const result = myArray.reduce((prev,cur) => {
    let obj = [];
    cur.riskTypeNo.split(';').forEach((n) => {
        obj.push({riskTypeNo: n, selectedValue: cur.selectedValue});
    });
    prev.push(...obj);
    return prev;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't want arrays within arrays.

Comment: Ok. The OP looks like arrays. Updated for one array.